# creating html table using <c:forEach>

Tags: html, css, jsp

```html
<tbody class=" highlight">
        <c:forEach items="${fields}"  var="fields"    varStatus="i"begin="0" end="4">
                                    <tr>
                                        <th style="border : 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15); background : white !important;max-width:30px;">
                                            <c:choose>
                                                <c:when test=" "></c:when>
                                                <c:otherwise></c:otherwise>
                                            </c:choose>
                                        </th>
                                    </tr>
                                     <tr style="border : 1px dotted rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);" class="tr_${i.index}_am disp-none ${i.index}am ${i.index}-time common-td"> 
                                        <td style="width:35px;background : white !important; vertical-align:center;">${i.index}</td> 
                                         <c:forEach begin="0" end="4">
                                            <td class="rowspaneven"                      id="${i.index}Slot">                        </td>
                                        </c:forEach> 
                                     </tr> 
                                </c:forEach>
               </tbody>
```

Hello there,
Please find the below snippet. I want to convert into <c:forEach>

```html
    <tbody>
      <tr class="row">
        <th class="head"></th>
        <th class="head"></th>
        <th class="head"> </th>
        <th class="head"></th>
        <th class="head"></th>
      </tr>
      <tr class="row">
        <td class="cell"></td>
        <td class="cell"></td>
        <td class="cell"></td>
        <td class="cell"></td>
        <td class="cell"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="row">
        <td class="cell"></td>
        <td class="cell"></td>
        <td class="cell"></td>
        <td class="cell"></td>
        <td class="cell"></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
```

but unable to do so,
Any help highly appreciated. I'm changing the  but no cells are appearing.

i tried this way but coudn't do `**enter code here**`

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've achieved the above one by this..

```html
<tbody class="word-break highlight">
                                        <tr>
                                            <c:forEach items="${some}"  var="item" varStatus="j" begin="0" end="4">
                                                <th style="border : 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15); background : white !important;max-width:30px;">
                                                </th>
                                            </c:forEach>    
                                        </tr>   
                                         <c:forEach var="k" begin="6" end="12">
                                            <tr>
                                                <c:forEach var="m" items="${something}" begin="0" end="4">
                                                     <td id="myid">
                                                     </td> 
                                                </c:forEach>
                                            </tr>
                                        </c:forEach> 
                                        </tbody>
```

Answer (score 0):

I used css to generate the table you can refer it:

```html
<%@ taglib prefix = "c" uri = "http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Title</title>
<style>
    .table {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: 2fr 10fr 15fr 10fr 30fr 7fr;
        margin-left: 5em;
        margin-right: 5em;
    }
    .ele {
        border: 1px black solid;
    }
    body {
        background-color: aliceblue;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class = "table">
        <div class="ele ele1" >ID</div>
        <div class="ele ele2" >FullName</div>
        <div class="ele ele3" >E-mail</div>
        <div class="ele ele4" >Time</div>
        <div class="ele ele5" >Message</div>
        <div class="ele ele6" >To Archive</div>
        <c:forEach var = "x" items = "${unarchived_requests}">
            <div class="ele ele1" ><c:out value = "${x.id}"/></div>
            <div class="ele ele2" ><c:out value = "${x.fullName}"/></div>
            <div class="ele ele3" ><c:out value = "${x.email}"/></div>
            <div class="ele ele4" ><c:out value = "${x.sendAt}"/></div>
            <div class="ele ele5" ><c:out value = "${x.message}"/></div>
            <div class="ele ele6">
                <form action="archive?id=${x.id}" method="post">
                    <button type="submit">Archive</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </c:forEach>
    </div>
</body>
```

You can use this:

```html
<table>
    <!-- here should go some titles... -->
    <tr>
        <th>ISBN</th>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Authors</th>
        <th>Version</th>
    </tr>
    <c:forEach begin="1" end= "${ no }" step="1" varStatus="loopCounter"
        value="${lstBooks}" var="book">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <c:out value="${book.isbn}" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <c:out value="${book.title}" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <c:out value="${book.authors}" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <c:out value="${book.version}" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    </c:forEach>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer , but i want to do that  in <table> tags only.

Comment: I have added one more method check it.